# Any fast way to back up all projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I have about 25 projects in Visual Studio 2015 /Projects folder. When I go to work I made change to some of its on a company PC. Then when go home I must delete /bin and /obj folders (using a self created tool) and make a 7z file (It take about 15 min with ultra mode 7-zip, file size about 300MB), upload to OneDrive and download and open in my home PC. It continue repeated like that. I did use GIT but I not always remember to sync every projects.

My question is have another way to do this faster? Can I using git for whole /Projects folder and how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Git is an efficient way to do that. You should be used to it after a period of usage.

If the 25 projects are related, you can manage them in one git repository. Otherwise you should manage them in different repositories.

More detail about git, you can refer [git book](https://www.git-scm.com/doc).

Answer (score 0):

Use git, its much safer when it comes to code rollback.

i found this tool which can help you to auto update your git repos

[git-repo-updater](https://github.com/earwig/git-repo-updater)

Comment: May be it's not what I want. I make many changes to projects and usually forgot to commit changes. I just want to backup whole projects folder

Comment: how hard is it to just commit the changes once you finish working?